# Skip the rendering of view in grails

Tags: grails

In Grails, there should be a matching GSP file for an action in a controller. For example, the action `list()` in a controller will render `list.gsp`.
Is there anyway we can skip this? Say I want my action: `writetoaFile()` to just generate a text file which is downloaded by the client browser and then NOT render the view.
I have already tried `return`, `return null` and `return false` without success. My code looks like:

```
def writetoaFile(){     
    response.setContentType("text/plain")
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=test.txt")
        response <<"Hello World"
    return
}
```

`writetoafile.gsp`'s code:

```
Hey There. This is a gsp file.
```

Now my application writes "Hello World" successfully to a file test.txt but it also writes writetoafile.gsp to the text file test.txt.

So my test.txt contains:

```
Hello World
Hey There. This is a gsp file.
```

I want to skip the view. I have tried:

1. `return`
2. `return null`
3. `return false`
4. `response.setContentType("text/plain")`
5. `response.setContentType("")`

Comment: You don't have to have a view associated with each controller method. You can always just (as the last line of the controller) do: render "some text" or even render ""

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code:

```
def writetoaFile(){  
    response.setContentType("text/plain")
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=test.txt")
    response <<"Hello World"
    response.flushBuffer()
}
```

Comment: In grails 1.3.7 I had better results with `response.outputStream << file.text
    response.outputStream.flush()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not calling your action through ajax try returning your response. Something like this.

```
def downloadMe ={
    response.contentType = grailsApplication.config.grails.mime.types["excel"]
    def fileName= "text.xlsx'
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
    return myWrite(response)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def writetoaFile(){     
 //Do whatever
    render ""
}
```

This renders a blank page. If you want some text you can put that in the render statement.

Comment: Hi BZ,
thanks for the reply but i can not use render because i am dynamically generating a text file based on some logic.

Comment: So what you're trying to do is generate the file, write it out to the file system and then render it?  Do you want the file to look like a page? Or do you want the viewer to be prompted to save it as a file etc?

Comment: If you just want the file rendered : you can do File t = new File(path/to/file);render t.text

Comment: I am not trying to render the file. I just want it to be downloaded to the file system.The browser must prompt to save it as a file

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following approaches (1 & 2, or 1 & 3)

1) explicit output stream (may not be required but give it a shot)

```
response.outputStream << "Hello world"
```

2) You can retrieve the GrailsWebRequest and [disable view rendering.](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/servlet/mvc/GrailsWebRequest.html#setRenderView%28boolean%29)

```
def webRequest = request.getAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.WEB_REQUEST)
webRequest.setRenderView(false)
```

3) [Use a filter](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters) and return false in the after->model closure to disable the default view rendering.